# Pair AirPods to tvOS 11

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, airpods

Using the public beta version of tvOS 11 on an AppleTV 4th-generation.

How to pair my AirPods ear buds?

This new [version 11 is supposed to make easy work of pairing](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/08/airpods-apple-tv-tvos-11/). But when I open the AirPods case next to the Apple TV, nothing happens. When I go to Settings > Video and Audio > Audio Output, all I see listed is "Apple TV" both when case is open nearby and when wearing the AirPods.

These AirPods are already paired with both my iPhone and Mac, without problems.

Comment: Same here. Airpods work great with all other devices but can't get them to work with Apple TV (tvOS 11). Basil, any luck?

Comment: @TomaszBanas Yes: Sign into iCloud on the AppleTV device. See [my Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/300651/17907).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sign in to iCloud

Apple shares the Bluetooth pairing info between all your Apple devices and the AirPods via your iCloud account.

On Apple TV, check the settings to see if you have signed into iCloud.

Once signed in, your AirPods appear in the audio settings list of sound outputs.

Also, in tvOS 11, as I recall, you may see AirPods appear as a sound option when displaying the screen-top menu in the Home screen. More convenient way to activate them than going into the nested settings menuing system.

Answer (score 1):

Pick up your AirPods charging case and open it.
Press and hold the pairing button on the back of the case.
Launch Settings on your Apple TV
Click on Remotes and Devices.
Click on Bluetooth.
Select your AirPods from the list.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207010

https://discussions.apple.com/message/31128330#31128330

https://www.imore.com/how-pair-your-airpods-apple-tv-android-and-other-bluetooth-devices

Comment: Thanks, but that is the *old* way, as if the Apple TV were not an Apple device. Reportedly, [tvOS 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TvOS#tvOS_11.x) debuting in 2017 brings new behavior: easy auto-pairing via iCloud, as seen with iPhone & Mac. See: https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/08/airpods-apple-tv-tvos-11/